# Throttle / Debounce numeric box inputs when up/down increment /decrement is clicked

Tags: r, shiny

I have a numeric box which triggers recalculation whenever someone clicks the increment or decrement widget in built.

This triggers unnecessary & distracting screen redraws. What's the way to avoid this?

I think it is the debounce() or throttle() functons I should be using but I cannot figure out how exactly.

```
  output$doctors_qty <- renderUI({

    code<-list()
    for( item in input$doctors)
    {
      inp_name<-paste("inp",item,sep = "_")
      inp_display_name<-paste("No. of Visits of",item,sep = " ")

      pre_value<-isolate(input[[paste("inp",item,sep="_")]])
      value_tmp<-ifelse(is.null(pre_value),1,pre_value) #Show 1 at first by default

      code<-list(code,numericInput(inp_name, inp_display_name,value=value_tmp,min = 0))
    }
    return(code)
  })
```

Comment: If you can provide a fully reproducible (and minimal) sample code, it'd be much easier to give you an answer

Comment: @daattali Sure. Good point. I will post it online in a bit.